The signs of some mean-zero random variables
Let $X$ be a discrete random variable supported on $\{−5,\dots, 6\}$ in which the outcomes have the following respective probabilities: $$\begin{array}{rc}
n & p(n) \\ \hline −5 & 6/36 \\ −4 & 0 \\ −3 & 0 \\ −2 & 6/36 \\ −1 & 5/36 \\
0 & 5/36 \\ 1 & 2/36 \\ 2 & 2/36 \\ 3 & 3/36 \\ 4 & 4/36 \\ 5 & 2/36 \\ 6 & 1/36 \end{array}$$
and let the random variable $S_n$ be the sum of $n$ IID copies of $X$. Since $X$ has expected value 0, so does $S_n$. Let $p_n$ be ${\rm Prob}[S_n > 0]$ and $q_n$ be ${\rm Prob}[S_n < 0]$, so that for instance $p_1 =14/36$ and $q_1 = 17/36 > p_1$. Is it true that $q_n > p_n$ for all $n$ besides $n=4$? (It is not hard to show that $p_4 > q_4$, and it has been checked that $q_n > p_n$ for all other $n$ up to 100.)
More broadly, one can ask what kinds of behavior the sign of $p_n-q_n$ can exhibit if we replace $X$ by an arbitrary finitely-supported integer-valued mean-zero random variable. Must the sign be eventually constant (as it appears to be in my specific example), or can it exhibit more complicated forms of behavior?

Have you tried looking at the Fourier transform of the distribution? I think you can describe $p$ and $q$ by weighted sums of powers of the coefficients, which might be helpful.

Have you tried graphing $p$ and $q$, by the way? Do they approach some values?

Alternatively maybe you can use the Cornish–Fisher expansion?

Hi @James Propp, this is not an answer. I am just suggesting a reformulation to see if that helps you. If the random variables had a density function (continuous case), they being iid, their joing deinsity would be self-convolution n times. Then what you are asking can be converted to a question of "does the RHS area of this density function exceed the LHS area, after n convolutions?" . I am thinking of approaching this as study of symetry in the smoothening property of convolution.

And given central limit theorem, I am intuitively inclined to think that if n is very large, the distribution of sum (average) will approach normal distribution, making the RHS and LHS areas becoming the same (it might still maintain sign in a limit sense)

@JamesPropp : Do you have a response to the answer below?

@Iosef Pinelis: I would accept it as an answer if it showed that $q_n > p_n$ for all $n>4$, not just for all sufficiently large $n$, with full details included.

@JamesPropp : Your original question was "Must the sign be eventually constant [...]?" It was not about all $n>4$.

@Iosif: I no longer remember the chronology of the different versions of my question. What I do know is that the person on whose behalf I posted the question wanted to know if the inequality holds for all $n>4$. If nobody responds with a more detailed analysis before the deadline, I will award the bounty to you.

It's likely to be helpful to express $X$ as $Y-Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent variables satisfying $\mbox{Prob}[Y=1] = \mbox{Prob}[Y=4] = 1/3$, $\mbox{Prob}[Y=5] = \mbox{Prob}[Y=6] = 1/6$, $\mbox{Prob}[Z=0] = \mbox{Prob}[Z=1] = \mbox{Prob}[Z=2] = 1/6$ and $\mbox{Prob}[Z=6] = 1/2$, satisfying $\mbox{Exp}[Y]=\mbox{Exp}[Z]=7/2$.

The sign will be eventually constant, except perhaps for a few special distributions of $X$.
This follows from the asymptotic expansion in powers of $n^{-1/2}$ of the cdf of the sum of iid integer-valued random variables with finite moments of some order -- see e.g. Theorem 6 in Section 3 of Chapter VI in Petrov's book.

How does the sign of $p_n-q_n$ connect with the asymp. expansion in powers of $n^{-1/2}$?

@MikeG : The connection of the cdf (say $G_n$) of the sum $S_n$ of iid integer-valued random variables is as follows: $p_n-q_n=1-G_n(0)-G_n(-1)$.
